# Using mockery, how do you make a method on mock expect a specific DateTime object

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4, mockery

I built some functionality around laravel 4's query builder, and to test out a certain part, i need to do something like this:

```
$dateTimeObject = new DateTime; // some other stuff with this object
$q->shouldReceive('where')->once()->with('baz', '>=', $dateTimeObject);
```

The issue is, that whenever I do this, mockery tries to convert it to a string, and i get the error:

```
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

How do I get round this ?

(I am using **phpunit** and **mockery** for testing)

Comment: it is not clear what the `$q->` part shoud do. if it is a query, i presume you have to deal with UNIX timestamps, not datetime objects. Anyway, what if you do `$dateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` ?

Comment: `$q` is a mock object, hence the shouldReceive , and i need to work with datetime objects

Comment: without seeing what you are actually testing against, it is a bit difficult for me to replicate the error, since if I mock $q as `$q = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model');` it will pass the test.